# how to find year and month difference between two dates?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DateTime dayStart;
DateTime dateEnd;

TimeSpan ts = dateEnt - dateStart;
```

Print : ... Year(s) and ... Month(s)

how can I calculate it?

.net framework 2.0
c#

asp.net project.

Comment: You need (a lot of) definitions here. How many months between 31-01-2011 and 01-02-2011?  If you want fractions, how long is a month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you want to calculate exactly.

You can't translate the value in a `TimeSpan` to exact years and months, as the length of years and months varies. You can calculate approximate years and months like this:

```
int years = ts.Days / 365;
int months = (ts.Days % 365) / 31;
```

If you want the exact difference, you have to compare the `DateTime` values.

Answer (score 7):

[You should first read this article](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), specially from the text "Introducing periods and period arithmetic" it gets interesting for you.

So, you have to define when a certain period is a change in month, in year etc.

[Noda-time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) already contains a lot of functions for this. But I don't think it is released yet.

Comment: Gah, what's the point of me coming to a question all excited by the prospect of mentioning Noda Time if other people do it for me? ;)

Comment: Wow, I'd never heard of Noda-Time, and never really thought about the complexity of calculating date/time spans.  Reading the link posted for the first time I keep thinking "Yeah.. That's right.  How come I never thought of that?"  +1 for posting it and again, thanks to the creators of StackOverflow for giving me something new to think about allowing this old dog to learn another new trick.

Comment: I wasn't really cross at all! It was lovely to see that there was actually a *point* to spending all the time writing the blog post :)

Answer (score 5):

Following will calculate the age in years, months, days

```
        DateTime dob = "10/18/1981";  // date of birth
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        // Swap them if one is bigger than the other
        if (now < dob)
        {
            DateTime date3 = now;
            now = dob;
            dob = date3;
        }
        TimeSpan ts = now - dob;
        //Debug.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays);

        int years = 0;
        int months = 0, days=0;
        if ((now.Month <= dob.Month) && (now.Day < dob.Day))  // i.e.  now = 03Jan15,  dob = 23dec14  
        {
            // example: March 2010 (3) and January 2011 (1); this should be 10 months.  // 12 - 3 + 1 = 10
            years = now.Year - dob.Year-1;
            months = 12 - dob.Month + now.Month-1;
            days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dob.Year, dob.Month) - dob.Day + now.Day;

            if(months==12)
            {
                months=0;
                years +=1;
            }
        }
        else if ((now.Month <= dob.Month) && (now.Day >= dob.Day)) // i.e.  now = 23Jan15,  dob = 20dec14  
        {
            // example: March 2010 (3) and January 2011 (1); this should be 10 months.  // 12 - 3 + 1 = 10
            years = now.Year - dob.Year - 1;
            months = 12 - dob.Month + now.Month;
            days = now.Day - dob.Day;
            if (months == 12)
            {
                months = 0;
                years += 1;
            }
        }
        else if ((now.Month > dob.Month) && (now.Day < dob.Day))  // i.e.  now = 18oct15,  dob = 22feb14  
        {
            years = now.Year - dob.Year;
            months = now.Month - dob.Month-1;
            days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dob.Year, dob.Month) - dob.Day + now.Day;
        }
        else if ((now.Month > dob.Month) && (now.Day >= dob.Day))  // i.e.  now = 22oct15,  dob = 18feb14  
        {
            years = now.Year - dob.Year;
            months = now.Month - dob.Month;
            days = now.Day - dob.Day;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Years: {0}, Months: {1}, Days: {2}", years, months, days);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this would do it:

```
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime(1973, 07, 20);
  DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2010, 01, 10);

  // Swap them if one is bigger than the other
  if (date2 < date1)
  {
    DateTime date3 = date2;
    date2 = date1;
    date1 = date3;
  }

  // Now date2 >= date1.

  TimeSpan ts = date2 - date1;

  // Total days
  Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays);

  // Total years
  int years = date2.Year - date1.Year;

  int months = 0;
  // Total monts
  if (date2.Month < date1.Month)
  {
    // example: March 2010 (3) and January 2011 (1); this should be 10 monts
    // 12 - 3 + 1 = 10
    // Take the 12 months of a year into account
    months = 12 - date1.Month + date2.Month;
  }
  else
  {
    months = date2.Month - date1.Month;
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Years: {0}, Months: {1}", years, months);
```

**Edit** To clarify: There's no need for complicated date algorhitms or any of that kind of stuff, because there are always 12 months in a year (at least in our calendar).