# Why I get an error when I try to display date minus date at C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, date

I am using ASP.NET MVC4.

I execute a query, and then I execute the following line

```
var dates = query.Select(x => x.Date - query.Min(y => y.Date));
```

What I want to do here, is to find the minimum date of my results from the query, and substract that date from all the dates.

I then have

```
    ViewBag.dates = dates;
```

and at my view I have

```
<%= Json.Encode(ViewBag.dates) %>
```

And I get this exception at the line I just mentioned

```
DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.
```

If I remove the `- query.Min(y => y.Date)` from the first line of code I wrote, my code executes fine. Why is that? and how I can fix that?

Comment: Check this for explanation why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820401/dbarithmeticexpression-arguments-must-have-a-numeric-common-type . To fix you can `ToList()` first and than do math on local query.

Comment: If there is the EntityFramework is involved you may face [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820401/dbarithmeticexpression-arguments-must-have-a-numeric-common-type

Comment: TimeSpan ts = date1 - date2; 

See this question you will find useful stuff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748323/how-to-find-year-and-month-difference-between-two-dates